# Getting bitmap image from camera intent as thumbnail.How to make it bigger

Tags: java, android, css, image, bitmap

I am trying to open my camera app and get the image onto an imageview.Even when i use wrap content for the imageview's width and height, it is shown as a thumbnail.I have seen several posts for resizing it and am not sure which one to use.The issue is that i want the image as it is , that is in its full size, not as a thumbnail.The following is what i have tried:

```
inside a button click event:   

 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 111);


@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 111) {
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                preview.setImageBitmap(photo);
}
```

I am trying to show the image as a preview inside an imageview.The issue is i want a bigger image.When i try changing the widht and height of the imageview to 300px and 150px , i get a blank.

How do i get a bigger image?

EDIT:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
         File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
         intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
         startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

In on activity result:

```
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
                    {
                        //Get our saved file into a bitmap object:
                       File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
                       Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 1000, 700);
                       preview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
        { // BEST QUALITY MATCH

            //First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

            // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and width of image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (height > reqHeight)
            {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
            }
            int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

            if (expectedWidth > reqWidth)
            {
                //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
            }

            options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        }
```

But still i get the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply the Intent with a putExtra option and a filename for where to store it. The extra data is just a snapshot.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
```

It'll save the image to the specified location (as long as it's writable and such)

Comment: I have tried that,But now i want to increase the size.So i did some changes.REFER EDIT